# Create deep copy in angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular

How I can create deep copy in angular 2, I tried to use `let newObject = Object.assign({}, myObject)` but still `myObject` reflects all the changes done in newObject.

Comment: I thinks its typescript problem not angular2. correct me if I m wrong

Comment: Do you mean deep copy or shallow copy? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy

Comment: @SurajRao ok now I am also confused, I just want to reset my object to its default state when my work is done with that object. So to do that, I need to store that default copy, but when I make changes at one place all other copy also gets changed. How to prevent that?

Comment: That means you need a deep copy.Better edit the question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript

Comment: prefer to use third party library like lodash, https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#cloneDeep

Comment: @A.T. `jQuery.extend()` works fine here & I am already using jquery in my project so what's the benefit of loading whole new lib just only for single purpose?

Comment: @DheerajAgrawal you didn't mention you are using jQuery any where, btw I am big fan of $, but I prefer lodash for angular development.

Comment: Hey! Don’t forget to mark your issue as resolved ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the following function :

```
/**
 * Returns a deep copy of the object
 */

public deepCopy(oldObj: any) :any {
    var newObj = oldObj;
    if (oldObj && typeof oldObj === "object") {
        newObj = Object.prototype.toString.call(oldObj) === "[object Array]" ? [] : {};
        for (var i in oldObj)
            newObj[i] = this.deepCopy(oldObj[i]);
    }
    return newObj;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the Lodash.js . Because angular 2 does not have any method for deep copy . for reference see :https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep

or You can use this javascript function

```
var copy = Object.assign({}, myObject);
```

Comment: Do you think including lodash just for this one feature is reasonable?
To add 2 numbers would you install math.js? So would you keep adding random third party libraries for every trivial task you run into?

Comment: that's why i have given the second option

Comment: I know but that is wrong sadly.. Please see the documentation:

Warning for Deep Clone

For deep cloning, we need to use other alternatives because Object.assign() copies property values. If the source value is a reference to an object, it only copies that reference value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign